# Trying to create new PostgreSQL user, but receiving the error: "psql: FATAL: password authentication failed for user"

Tags: sql, postgresql, authentication, psql

I am trying to create another superuser for my Postgresql database. I have managed to successfully create a new role with all the permissions using default `postgres` superuser.

However, when I am trying to log into the database using my new user with the password I have created for it, I am getting this error message: `psql: error: could not connect to server: FATAL:  password authentication failed for user "newuser"`

Here is how my `pg_hba.conf` file looks like:

```
# TYPE  DATABASE        USER            ADDRESS                 METHOD

# IPv4 local connections:
host    all             all             127.0.0.1/32            md5
# IPv6 local connections:
host    all             all             ::1/128                 md5
# Allow replication connections from localhost, by a user with the
# replication privilege.
host    replication     all             127.0.0.1/32            md5
host    replication     all             ::1/128                 md5
```

If I set all the methods to `trust`, I will be able to log in as the `newuser`, but since the database I am trying to set up will be public, I do not want to leave superuser without any passwords.

Also, the default `postgres` user also already has the password set up for it, but I can log into it with no issues.

Comment: What command did you use to create the newuser?

Comment: @richyen the normal `CREATE ROLE newuser WITH LOGIN  PASSWORD 'secret' SUPERUSER CREATEDB CREATEROLE NOINHERIT BYPASSRLS;`

Comment: The server does not send to the full details to the unauthenticated user (presumed to be hostile).  Look in the server log file for the full error message.  Also, if postgres can log in without a password, then you have not shown us the full active pg_hba.conf.  Please show all uncommented lines.

Comment: Or if you are using v10 or above, please show output of `select * from pg_hba_file_rules`

Comment: +1 what @jjanes said.  Also, if what you have shared is true, it sounds like your app might be mangling your password (i.e., if you are passing it in via commandline, and you have an `!` in the password, maybe you need to escape the special char(s))